# Fast search through QTableWidget rows

Tags: c++, qt5, qtablewidget

I need to search rows through a `QTableWidget`. Each of the rows in the table contains a field with date and I need to show only rows that are within a specified date interval based on user input. Here is my function:

```
void nvr::sort()
{

QTableWidget* tabela = this->findChild<QTableWidget*>("NCtable");



QDateEdit* c1 = this->findChild<QDateEdit*>("c1");

QDateEdit* c2 = this->findChild<QDateEdit*>("c2");

// user specified ranges for date
QDate date1 = c1->date();

QDate date2 = c2->date();

//row numbers in table
int rowsNum = tabela->rowCount();

// hide all rows
for(int z = 0; z < rowsNum; z++) {

    tabela->hideRow(z);

}

// show only rows that are within range
for(int z = 0; z < rowsNum; z++) {


    QDateTime dateTime = QDateTime::fromString(tabela->item(z,2)->text(),"dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm");

    QDate date = dateTime.date();

    //date compares
    if ( (date1.operator <=(date)) && (date2.operator >=(date) ) ) {

    tabela->showRow(z);

    }



   }



}
```

This works fine if i have 200 rows. But when i have 30 000 rows and i surely will, the gui freezes because i suppose the function executes very slow. Any suggestions for faster execution?

Comment: What about storing your data in a QVector(sorted by date1 for example?), loop on that when the user input the dates, add the valid ones to a QStandardItemModel, and show it with QTableView. If the user changes those dates, you just clear the QStandardItemModel and restart the process. This should work easily for 30 000 rows.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to reproduce your problem, but here is the approach I would take:

- Create a custom class to store the data of one row, let's call it
  `DataRow`.
- Store those in a `QVector<DataRow>`, that you can sort by Date1 for example.
- Loop through this `QVector<DataRow>` and find the elements that correspond to the criteria.
- Add those `DataRow` to a class derived from `QAbstractItemModel`.
- Show this model derived from `QAbstractItemModel` with a `QTableView`.

`QTableWidget` is heavyweight and was not really built for speed. It's really convenient to build something quickly with few elements though.
`QTableView` is the one you want, with a custom model inherited from  `QAbstractItemModel`.

Then, when the user requests a new input, you could just wipe the model and restart the process. This is not optimal, but the user should not see the difference. Feel free to add more logic here to keep the good elements and only remove the bad ones.

About the GUI freezing, one way to always avoid that is to have the GUI thread separated from other worker threads. The [QThread](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html) documentation is exhaustive and can help you set up something like this.